# From string to hardcode (C# HashTables)

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a HashTable called casillas in which keys are numbers from 1 to 68 and values are strings like:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[8]
```

This allows me to easily refer to a specific cell in the `dataGrid`, but how can I use it to access things like cells Style?

I want to do something like:

```
casillas[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Purple;
```

Comment: Why put strings inside the HashTable?  You can key on the Cell itself.

Comment: I've just tried it without strings (deleting the "" I've written when adding values) and it's still not working

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the hastable to store references to cells instead:

```
int rowIndex = 0;
int colIndex = 8;
casillas[1] = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex];
```

Now you can access the properties of the cells via your hashtable:

```
casillas[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Purple;
```

Comment: Tried it and still not working. When I write casillas[1]. Equals, GetHashCode, GetType and ToString appear in the list, and if I continue to write casillas[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Purple throws an error.

Comment: @Y.Costela, yes it's an object ref. you can simply cast it.

Comment: @xdtTransform how should I cast it? Now I have a sentence like casillas[17] = dataGridView.Rows[9].Cells[18];

Comment: Cast it to `DataGridViewCell` - `((DataGridViewCell)casillas[17]).Style.BackColor = Color.Purple`

Answer (score -2):

I had to create a new variable of type DataGridViewTextBoxCell (called cas, for example) equal to casillas[X] and then apply the changes I wanted to that new variable named cas.